# How can I remove chapter 0 in the front matter (acknowledgement, toc,nomenclature) when using fancyhdr

Tags: fancyhdr, front-matter

These are my settings for [`fancyhdr`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr):

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[RE]{Chapter \thechapter}
\fancyhead[LO]{\textit{\nouppercase{\leftmark}}}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
```

Answer (score 4):

Under the default `book` document class, this is what `\frontmatter` does:

```
\newcommand\frontmatter{%
  \cleardoublepage
  \@mainmatterfalse
  \pagenumbering{roman}}
```

Note that it sets a conditional - `\if@mainmatter` - to `false`. We can use this as part of the header setting:

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{fancyhdr,lipsum}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}% Clear header/footer
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\makeatletter
\fancyhead[RE]{\if@mainmatter Chapter \thechapter\fi}
\makeatother
\fancyhead[LO]{\textit{\nouppercase{\leftmark}}}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\chapter{Front matter chapter}
\lipsum[1-10]

\mainmatter

\chapter{Main matter chapter}
\lipsum[1-10]

\end{document}
```

Comment: It doesn't work for me I've got Incomplete \ifx; using it in \fancyhead[LE]{\if@mainmatter \nouppercase\chaptername\ \thechapter}

Comment: @GM: You need a closing `\fi` in that conditional: `\fancyhead[LE]{\if@mainmatter \nouppercase\chaptername\ \thechapter\fi}`

Answer (score 0):

Simply instead of using this command :

`fancyhead[RE]{Chapter \thechapter}`

you only have to modify the case in which you would like to visualize the chapter :

```
\fancyhead[RE]{\ifnum \value{chapter}>0
Chapter \thechapter\fi}
```

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)!

Comment: Doesnt work for me I got an Incomplete \ifx;

Comment: Sorry I just discoverted that I was missing the final \fi if you can edit I will reverse the downvote